# How would I calculate how much memory can be addressed by the paging solution?

Tags: architecture, memory

Given a modern 64-bit architecture with 6-bytes used for each page pointer, 1 MB pages, and 16 GB installed memory:

a) How would I calculate how much memory can be addressed by the paging solution?

b) How would I calculate how large must each page table be?

I'm not looking for the answer. I would just appreciate a clear breakdown.

Comment: In theory, or for real contemporary processors (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#Limitations_of_practical_processors)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64 bit architecture allows 2<sup>64</sup> bytes to be addressed.

Six bytes is 48 bits, so the number of pages that can be addressed with a six byte page pointer is 2<sup>48</sup>.  Multiply that by a million to get the number of addressable bytes using 1 megabyte pages.

16 Gigabytes is approximately 2<sup>30</sup>, and the paging solution already exceeds that capacity, even with a page size of 1 byte.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the breakdown would look like this: 2^48 * 2^10 which translates into 2^58 byte giving you and addressable amount of  2^18 TB?

Comment: Where did you get 2^10 from?

Comment: Page size is 1024 bytes (2^10), right? or am I mistaken

Comment: It says in your question that page size is one megabyte.